# Get "this" element ID in jQuery live/delegate with timeout

Tags: javascript, binding, jquery

I am trying to get the ID of an element bound with a jQuery delegate() function. I want to pass the element's ID to another function. The ID returned is always "undefined" and I'm not sure why. Here is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeout = undefined;
  $('body').delegate(
    '#tab-form input[type="text"]',
    'keypress',
    function(){
      if(timeout != undefined) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = undefined;
        alert($(this).attr('id'));
      }, 500);
    }
  );
});
```

And my markup:

```
<form id="tab-form">
  <input type="text" value="" id="Tab_name" name="Tab[name]">
  <input type="text" value="" id="Tab_text" name="Tab[text]">
</form>
```

Making a keypress in the text input pops up a JS alert that says "undefined", instead of "Tab_name" or "Tab_text" like I imagined it would.

My initial Googling around leads me to believe that the reason for the attr('id') being *undefined* is that "this" is not actually a single DOM element, but is an array of the elements that delegate() is attached to. I have not been able to figure out how to access the *current* bound element's DOM object in the jQuery object array.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: I don't have an answer to your problem, but you might want to change that keypress for keydown or keyup because keypress has some issues in some browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The context is `window` because `window` owns `setTimeout`. Just cache it:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeout = undefined;
  $('body').delegate(
    '#tab-form input[type="text"]',
    'keypress',
    function(){
      var el = this;
      if(timeout != undefined) {
        clearTimeout(timeout);
      }
      timeout = setTimeout(function() {
        timeout = undefined;
        alert($(el).attr('id'));
      }, 500);
    }
  );
});
```

Comment: this is what I ended up doing since it seemed like the most simple and straightforward approach to me in this case

Answer (score 2):

It's because `this` isn't what you want it to be in that anonymous function, it's `window`.  There are a few ways to solve this, for example using [`$.proxy()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/), like this:

```
  timeout = setTimeout($.proxy(function() {
    timeout = undefined;
    alert(this.id);
  }, this), 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

`meder` already pointed out the reason for the behavior. You might also pass in the `event object` and use `target`:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var timeout = undefined;
  $('body').delegate(
    '#tab-form input[type="text"]',
    'keypress',
     function(event){
        if(timeout != undefined) {
           clearTimeout(timeout);
        }
        timeout = setTimeout(function() {
           timeout = undefined;
           alert($(event.target).attr('id'));
     }, 500);
   }
 );
});
```

Sidenote: using `.delegate()` on the document.body does not make sense at all. You could just bind those events with `.live()` to your elements.

Comment: On the sidenote, you are right (I think) after looking into the difference between live and delegate. I was copying the way Yii is doing binding, which they just changed from live to delegate for some bug fix (http://code.google.com/p/yii/issues/detail?id=1031). But yes, I might as well just bind to the form instead of body.

Answer (score 0):

Since the other options are spoken for, I'll give the `closure` option. :o)

```
(function( th ) {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    timeout = undefined;
    alert(th.id);
  }, 500);
})( this );
```

---

**EDIT:** To explain what is happening, basically you're creating a function, calling the function and passing in `this` as the argument to the function all at the same time.

Think of it this way:

```
  // Create a new function that accepts one argument
function myFunc( th ) {
  timeout = setTimeout(function() {
    timeout = undefined;
    alert(th.id);
  }, 500);
}

  // Immediately call the function, and pass "this" in to it
myFunc( this );
```

This is the exact same thing. Take this, wrap the entire function in `()`, make it anonymous by removing the name of the function `myFunc`, and then take the execution operator `( this )` from the function call, and place it directly after the function.

When you do that, you're essentially *calling* the function just after you've created it. It is just an easy way of immediately executing an unnamed (anonymous) function.

Comment: what syntax voodoo is this? just ran it and it works, but, man, I have not seen that before

Comment: @thaddeusmt - It is a closure, and is a *very* useful feature of javascript. Basically, you're creating a new scope inside of a function body, calling the function and passing in `this` as a argument, and referencing the argument with the `th` parameter. I'll update my answer with a further explanation of the closure.